# Cannot shuffle list in Python

Tags: python, list, random

This is my list:

```
biglist = [ {'title':'U2','link':'u2.com'}, {'title':'beatles','link':'beatles.com'} ]
print random.shuffle(biglist)
```

that doesn't work!  It returns none.

Comment: Related/dupe: [Why does `random.shuffle` return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649875/why-does-random-shuffle-return-none)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`random.shuffle` shuffles the list, it does not return a new list. So check `biglist`, not the result of `random.shuffle`.

Documentation for the `random` module: http://docs.python.org/library/random.html

Comment: This is a really common mistake, I used to do it a lot with .reverse() and .sort()

Comment: Me too, hooray for `reversed()` and `sorted()`.