# Why does random.shuffle return None?

Tags: python, list, random, shuffle

Why is `random.shuffle` returning `None` in Python?

```
>>> x = ['foo','bar','black','sheep']
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> print shuffle(x)
None
```

How do I get the shuffled value instead of `None`?

Comment: Related: [sort() and reverse() functions do not work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16460616)

Comment: Also related: [Why doesn't calling a Python string method do anything unless you assign its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out)

Comment: Related: [Why do these list methods (append, sort, extend, remove, clear, reverse) return None rather than the resulting list?](/q/11205254/4518341)

Answer (score 255, accepted):

[`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) changes the `x` list **in place**.

Python API methods that alter a structure in-place generally return `None`, not the modified data structure.

```
>>> x = ['foo', 'bar', 'black', 'sheep']
>>> random.shuffle(x)
>>> x
['black', 'bar', 'sheep', 'foo']
```

---

If you wanted to create a **new** randomly-shuffled list based on an existing one, where the existing list is kept in order, you could use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) with the full length of the input:

```
random.sample(x, len(x))
```

You could also use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) with [`random.random()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random) for a sorting key:

```
shuffled = sorted(x, key=lambda k: random.random())
```

but this invokes sorting (an O(N log N) operation), while sampling to the input length only takes O(N) operations (the same process as `random.shuffle()` is used, swapping out random values from a shrinking pool).

Demo:

```
>>> import random
>>> x = ['foo', 'bar', 'black', 'sheep']
>>> random.sample(x, len(x))
['bar', 'sheep', 'black', 'foo']
>>> sorted(x, key=lambda k: random.random())
['sheep', 'foo', 'black', 'bar']
>>> x
['foo', 'bar', 'black', 'sheep']
```

Comment: Is using a random-valued `key` function truly guaranteed?  Some fast sorting algorithms fall over if comparisons are not self-consistent.  I can see this working either way, depending on implementation (decorate-sort-undecorate will only need to apply `key` once on each element so will be well-defined).

Comment: @torek: Python uses decorate-sort-undecorate when sorting with a `key` callable. So yes, it’s guaranteed as each value is given their random key exactly once.

Answer (score 52):

This method works too.

```
import random
shuffled = random.sample(original, len(original))
```

Answer (score 13):

## Why, really?

### 1. Efficiency

`shuffle` modifies the list in place.
This is nice, because copying a large list would be pure overhead if you do not need the original list anymore.

### 2. Pythonic style

According to the *"explicit is better than implicit"* principle of [pythonic style](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), returning the list would be a bad idea, because then one might think it *is* a new one although in fact it is not.

### But I don't like it like this!

If you *do* need a fresh list, you will have to write something like

```
new_x = list(x)  # make a copy
random.shuffle(new_x)
```

which is nicely explicit.
If you need this idiom frequently, wrap it in a function `shuffled` (see `sorted`) that returns `new_x`.

Answer (score 8):

According to [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

> Shuffle the sequence x in place. The optional argument random is a
>   0-argument function returning a random float in [0.0, 1.0); by
>   default, this is the function random().

```
>>> x = ['foo','bar','black','sheep']
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> shuffle(x)
>>> x
['bar', 'black', 'sheep', 'foo']
```

Answer (score 2):

I had my aha moment with this concept like this:

```
from random import shuffle
x = ['foo','black','sheep'] #original list
y = list(x) # an independent copy of the original
for i in range(5):
    print shuffle(y) # shuffles the original "in place" prints "None" return
    print x,y #prints original, and shuffled independent copy

>>>
None
['foo', 'black', 'sheep'] ['foo', 'black', 'sheep']
None
['foo', 'black', 'sheep'] ['black', 'foo', 'sheep']
None
['foo', 'black', 'sheep'] ['sheep', 'black', 'foo']
None
['foo', 'black', 'sheep'] ['black', 'foo', 'sheep']
None
['foo', 'black', 'sheep'] ['sheep', 'black', 'foo']
```

Comment: Because python does "copy-by-values" by default instead of pass-by-reference =) http://stackoverflow.com/a/986495/610569