# Make foo.sort() and other methods return

Tags: python, python-2.7, methods

In Python, whenever I try to use `.sort()` or a `random.shuffle()` on a list like such:

```
a = [1, 3, 2].sort()
b = random.shuffle([1, 3, 2])
```

The `a` and `b` will be `None` as both methods return `None`.

Of course, I am aware that there is a `sorted()` function for `.sort()`. However, the `random.shuffle()` does not. So the fix for this is to do:

```
a = [1, 3, 2]
random.shuffle(a)
b = a
```

or from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649875/why-does-random-shuffle-return-none):

```
b = sorted([1, 3, 2], key=lambda k: random.random())
```

Is there a general and elegant way to store literals, edited by methods that return `None`, into a variable?

Comment: Why not just write your own `shuffled` that copies, shuffles and returns an iterable argument? Those methods alter their argument in-place, so you already have a reference to the result; *it's the same object you passed in*. `b = a` could happen before or after with the same result - it's just a reference, **not** a copy.

Comment: I've edited out *"immediate"* because it's unclear what you mean - are you referring to *literals*?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to literals.

Comment: Then no, there is no general way - in the `.sort` case (or anything else with a deterministic outcome) you *write the literal in order* and if it needs to be random just manipulate it on a second line. That would be more explicit than the random sort you show.

Comment: I see. The `.sort()` was a bad example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [1, 3, 2]
b = random.shuffle(a) or a[:]
```

This will shuffle `a`, and point `b` to a copy of it.

`or` - used to chain, returns first truth value (or last false)

`a[:]` - copies `a`

**Note**: the original `a` *will* change. [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) modifies any list it is given (from the docs):

> Shuffle the sequence x *in place*...

My advice is just write your own shuffle method.

Comment: But you can't do this with a literal in one line, and it *doesn't* prevent the original being modified like `sorted` does. The fact that the OP has accepted this leaves me more confused than their question did; I'm not sure they even know what they're looking for.

Comment: @jonrsharpe added clarification. I tend to agree but now can't delete accepted answer.

Comment: Well, you can: `b = [(random.shuffle(x), x) for x in [a[:]]][0][1]`

Comment: @DanD. Ok, but that's: 1. Not the same thing (I was referring to using `or`); and 2. Almost unreadable!