# How to shuffle the order in a list?

Tags: python, arrays

I would like to shuffle the order of the elements in a list.

```
from random import shuffle
words = ['red', 'adventure', 'cat', 'cat']
shuffled = shuffle(words)
print(shuffled) # expect new order for, example ['cat', 'red', 'adventure', 'cat']
```

As response I get `None`, why?

Comment: "I tried with shuffle from random library but it gives me a None error." You need to show us what you actually did.

Comment: `None` is not an error. `random.shuffle()` shuffles the list in place and returns `None`. Check the contents of `words` after shuffling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does random.shuffle return None?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649875/why-does-random-shuffle-return-none)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's because `random.shuffle` shuffles in place and doesn't return anything (thus why you get `None`).

```
import random

words = ['red', 'adventure', 'cat', 'cat']
random.shuffle(words)

print(words) # Possible Output: ['cat', 'cat', 'red', 'adventure']
```

**Edit:**

Given your edit, what you need to change is:

```
from random import shuffle

words = ['red', 'adventure', 'cat', 'cat']
newwords = words[:] # Copy words
shuffle(newwords) # Shuffle newwords

print(newwords) # Possible Output: ['cat', 'cat', 'red', 'adventure']
```

or

```
from random import sample

words = ['red', 'adventure', 'cat', 'cat']
newwords = sample(words, len(words)) # Copy and shuffle

print(newwords) # Possible Output: ['cat', 'cat', 'red', 'adventure']
```

Comment: @Lindow You might have done it like `words = random.shuffle(words)` or `print(random.shuffle(words))` which is why it would print `None`.

Comment: what do you mean by "shuffles in place and doesn't return anything"? How copying the list solved the problem? what is difference between a list and copy of the list?

Comment: @Reihan_amn For instance `sorted` returns a new list and doesn't change the given list. Whereas `shuffle` changes the given list and doesn't return a new/copy.

Answer (score 2):

random.shuffle() is a method that does not have a return value.  So when you assign it to a identifier  (a variable, like x) it returns 'none'.

Comment: Nice answer but perhaps edit to show how to print the correct list.