# how shuffle different 3-dimentionl, 2-dimentional list to same random in python, tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

list `X[1, 100, 5]`, `list Y[1, 100]` is in `python`, `tensorflow`

I want to shuffle, `X's 100` and `Y's 100` to same random.

```
X = random.shuffle(X[0])
Y=random.shuffle(Y[0])

together = zip(X[0], Y[0])
together_shuffle = random.shuffle(together)

together_shuffle= zip(*together_shuffle)
X[0] = together_shuffle[0]
Y[0] = together_shuffle[1]
```

Is this right?

How can i do?

Comment: Where is tensorflow in this code? If `X` and `Y` are Tensors then you can't apply `random.shuffle` to them.

Comment: sorry. X, Y is np.array not list. so i use sklearn.utils.shuffle(x, Y, random_stats =0). but, I don't know that is correct. if i use sklearn's shuffle , can i shuffle X'100 and Y'100 to same random?

Answer (score 0):

In my code this returns a noneType since your manipulating list... but buy using `random.sample` it is working fine, as explained here : [Why does random.shuffle return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649875/why-does-random-shuffle-return-none)

as for selecting the first two coordinate of X i don't think it's going to work like that maybe you want to extract them by hand like `AUX = X[:,:,0]` if i understood what you wanted

Comment: sorry. X, Y is np.array not list. 
so i use sklearn.utils.shuffle(x, Y, random_stats =0).

but, I don't know that is correct.

if i use sklearn's shuffle , can i shuffle X'100 and Y'100 to same random?

Comment: yes but (if i understood correctly ) you want to shuffle the result of the 'zipping' of X and Y 
And zip() returns a list as said in here : https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: I don't know about sklearn's shuffle tho but if you want to shuffle the arrays without loosing the placement information above answer is correct