# Functionally shuffling a list

Tags: python, list, random

There are quite a few [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects) on stack overflow regarding the `random.shuffle` method of the random module.

Something that irks me about `shuffle` is that it shuffles in-place rather than returning a shuffled copy.

> Note that shuffle works in place, and returns None.

Therefore expressions like

```
for index, (parent1, parent2) in enumerate(zip(sorted(population)[::2], shuffle(population)[1::2])):
```

don't work. Writing it with a side effect seems unnecessarily verbose:

```
other_half = population[1::2]
random.shuffle(other_half)
for index, (parent1, parent2) in enumerate(zip(sorted(population)[::2], other_half):
```

What's a pythonic way of functionally shuffling a list?

Answer (score 2):

A good alternative would be [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.sample) with `k` being the `len` of the list:

```
import random

li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for _ in range(4):  # showing we get a new, 'shuffled' list
    print(random.sample(li, len(li)))

# [5, 2, 3, 1, 4]
# [1, 5, 4, 3, 2]
# [4, 2, 5, 1, 3]
# [4, 2, 3, 5, 1]
```

Comment: I like this approach. I would like to know if there are any reasonable alternatives. In my opinion the `sample` approach obfuscates the intent a little.

Comment: @SebastianWozny I think that's debatable. If you pick `x` random elements from a list with `x` elements then you are essentially shuffling the list. However, you may always wrap it with your own function with your own name.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17649901/4453817)

The accepted answer was

```
shuffled = sorted(x, key=lambda k: random.random())
```

Comment: It does indeed look like a duplicate. I find the title misleading on the other question, also because it didn't turn up in my google search for the problem. Maybe there is value of keeping the question here with your link.