# cant get random.shuffle to work python random.shuffle()

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

## **Right now I am trying to do a piece of code for the Monty Hall problem**

I have some code that I am trying to fix and then enhance

**This is one thing that I am stuck on:**

***I am trying to change the way the door at which the prize is chosen by using random.shuffle(), I have to use random.shuffle(), not anything else.***

**How would I do this?**

What I have now does not work for that.
if I put `print(random.shuffle(door))`, I don't get a new output.
how do I make it return the chosen output

```python-3
import random
door = ["goat","goat","car"]

choice = int(input("Door 1, 2 or 3? "))

otherDoor = 0
goatDoor = 0

if choice == 1:
    if door[1] == "goat":
        otherDoor = 3 
        goatDoor = 2
    elif door[2] == "goat":
        otherDoor = 2
        goatDoor = 3  
elif choice == 2:
    if door[0] == "goat":
        otherDoor = 3
        goatDoor = 1
    elif door[2] == "goat":
        otherDoor = 1
        goatDoor = 3
elif choice == 3:
 if door[0] == "goat":
     otherDoor = 2
     goatDoor = 1
 elif door[1] == "goat":
     otherDoor = 1
     goatDoor = 2

switch = input("There is a goat behind door " + str(goatDoor) +\
               " switch to door " + str(otherDoor) + "? (y/n) ")

if switch == "y":
    choice = otherDoor

if random.shuffle(door) == "car":
    print("You won a car!")
else:
    print("You won a goat!")

input("Press enter to exit.")
```

---

Comment: You need to pay closer attention to the [answers to the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17649901/10077). `random.shuffle()` **does not return anything**. It shuffles the list in-place.

Comment: `random.shuffle()` does just that... It shuffles the data. It's not *supposed* to output anything.

Answer (score 1):

`random.shuffle` shuffles in place, meaning it will return `None` if you try and assign a variable to it's non-existent output.

Since you say you have to use `shuffle`, you can shuffle the list in place with `random.shuffle(door)`, then take an element from this shuffled list eg: `door[0]`

Answer (score 0):

From the [python3 documentation of the random module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

> random.shuffle(x[, random]) 
>   Shuffle the sequence x in place.

The 'in place' means that the function is replacing the variable x (in your case, 'door') with a different variable that has the same values as before but with their order shuffled. It does not have a return, it simply modifies the variable you gave it, which is why your print statement shows 'None'.

If you must use, `random.shuffle`, you can simply select an element of the door after you've shuffled it  (i.e. `random.shuffle(door)` then `print(door[0])`).

However, if other functions were to be an option, then `random.sample(door,1)` may be simpler instead (documentation for random.sample [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)).