# Unexpected None printed after shuffling list

Tags: python

```
from random import *
day = list(range(1, 29))
day = day[3:29]
shuffleday = shuffle(day)
print(shuffleday)
```

The result is `None`. What's wrong?

Comment: Please do a search before posting a new question - this one [already has many answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+shuffle+returns+none), e.g. [Why does random.shuffle return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17649875/12299000)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

`random.shuffle` *modifies* `day`. It does not return anything.

This is per convention in Python, where functions which modify the arguments given to them return `None`.

If you wish to generate a new list shuffled, without modifying the original, you may wish to use `random.sample`.

```
from random import *

day = list(range(1, 29))
shuffleday = sample(day[3:29], len(day2))
print(shuffleday)
```

If you simply wish to get *a* random element from a list, you can use `random.choice`.

```
from random import *

day = list(range(1, 29))
randomday = choice(day[3:29])
print(randomday)
```

Answer (score 0):

[random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) does not return anything. It modifies the input list.

```
import random

day=list(range(1,29))
print(day)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
day=day[3:29]
print(day)
# [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]

shuffleday=random.shuffle(day)
print(shuffleday)
# None
print(day)
# [27, 9, 14, 15, 7, 17, 28, 10, 23, 21, 16, 12, 6, 11, 22, 25, 24, 20, 5, 19, 13, 4, 18, 8, 26]
```

Comment: I'm trying to get a random number out of there. What function would be good?

Comment: Add the following code to below of your code "random.choice(day)"

Answer (score 0):

The value of `shuffleday` is `None` because the `shuffle` function does not return a new list, it just changes the order of the elements in the list supplied as an argument.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To get a random number from day list use `choice` instead of `shuffle`, it will return a value of random element from `day[3:29]`:

```
from random import *
day = list(range(1, 29))
day = day[3:29]
shuffleday = choice(day)
print(shuffleday)
```

Comment: While this code may do what the user is trying to accomplish, this answer does not directly answer the core question.

Comment: Plus 1 for reminding. Yes, OP didn't tell the expected result. Already voted to clarify for more details.

Comment: The question seemed to be a pretty clear "why is this printing `None`?"

Comment: This is not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

This will return a value of random number. Choose one:

```
shuffleday = choice(range(3,29))
```

or

```
shuffleday = randint(3,29)
```

or

```
shuffleday = randrange(3,29)
```

Comment: As stated on another answer, while this code may do what the user is trying to accomplish, this answer does not directly answer the core question.

Comment: This is not answer the question

Answer (score -1):

`random.shuffle` modifies the list in place, it doesn't return a value. so you can just replace your second last line with

```
shuffle(day)
```

then simply print shuffle without making your new variable.

Additionally I would say it's better practice to just import what you need from `random`, rather than doing a `*` import and cluttering your namespace (especially considering you are new to the language and unlikely to know the name of every function in the random library). In this case you can do:

```
from random import shuffle
```

Comment: So what kind of random function returns a value?

Comment: You could instead start by making your copy first (ie shuffleday = day.copy()) and then shuffle your new list. You would only need to do this if you need the original list later in the code, otherwise you should just shuffle your original list and save the memory.

Answer (score -1):

in fact the `shuffle` function does not return anything, it shuffles the elements in place (in `day` for your case).

try `print(day)` instead

Comment: I'm trying to get a random number out of there. What function would be good?

Comment: just do `day = randint(3,29)`