# Shuffling a list without changing the original list

Tags: python, list, variables, random

Say that I have a list with elements:

`listA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

print(listA) returns:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

I want to randomize the elements in `listA`, but then store this information in `listB`

```
import random
listB = random.shuffle(listA)
```

but if I print `listB`, it returns `None`

```
print(listB)
None
```

Instead, if I print `listA`, it returns the randomized list

```
print(listA)
[3, 2, 1, 4, 5]
```

What is going on here? How to I re-declare a variable with a new name after applying a function?

Comment: `random.shuffle` modifies the list in-place. This is [*clearly documented*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) function.

```
import random

listA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
listB = random.sample(listA, len(listA))
```

Comment: As already shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17649901) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27882193).